# Android: Activity from tab menu

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, tabs

I have this tab menu with 3 buttons and I want an activity to be embed (get started) when user pushes one of the buttons. Here's the code, how do I do it? :)

```
private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
        View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);

        TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {return view;}
        });
        mTabHost.addTab(setContent);

    }

    private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
        tv.setText(text);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run through the [Tab Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) tutorial?
Though, I am not quite sure what your question is.